# How can I reverse engineer an Android app?

Tags: android, api, sdk, reverse-engineering

Concretely, I have a camera stabilizer (the Hohem ISteady pro 3) and I want to be able to control it via my own app or at least code.

Unfortunately, the app is compiled (I think this is the name ?) using a Tencent tools and the only way I could theoretically get the source code is by getting them from the memory of a rooted phone as the app is running...

As the app uses Bluetooth to communicate to the stabilizer, could I intercept the info that are sent and use that in my code ? As I don't see any other way and as the company doesn't provide any kind of API or SDK, what can I do ?

Comment: Do you have access to the apk?

Answer (score 0):

you can use apktool (it decompiles .dex to .smali and you can recompile it), jadx (it has a GUI too - jadx-gui) (it decompiles .dex to .java but not completely) or fernflower (it decompiles .jar to .java (you need to dex2jar to decompile .dex to .jar) but not completely)

Comment: I decompiled it, but it was compiled using a tencent tool that prevent people to, well, do what I'm trying x) The source code is hidden, and you find a file that leads to Tencent